# Can a querystring in a URL be protected from sniffing without HTTPS?

Tags: web-application

I was using wireshark and expecting to see a JSESSIONID in a HTTP request, but it did not seem to be there for HTTP requests. I could see my own JSESSIONID however. Would upgrade-insecure-requests help protect a query string form sniffing?

Answer (score 1):

> I was using wireshark and expecting to see a JSESSIONID in a HTTP
>   request, but it did not seem to be there for HTTP requests. I could
>   see my own JSESSIONID however.

JSESSIONID is a cookie that is usually flagged with the "secure" and "no script" flags. The "secure" flag tells compliant browsers to not send that cookie over HTTP, only HTTPS.

> Would upgrade-insecure-requests help protect a query string form sniffing?

The HTTP Upgrade-Insecure-Requests request header sends a signal to the server expressing the client’s preference for an encrypted and authenticated response... more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade-Insecure-Requests

If the server receives the request with `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` it can redirect the client that expressed the preference for secure requests to the HTTPS version of the site.

**IN GENERAL:**

Query string is part of the URL in the request. The URL appears in the request line of the HTTP request:

```
GET /some/url?a=b HTTP/1.1
```

To protect it from sniffing you need SSL/TLS that establishes a secure TCP session before sending data and then encrypts the communication/data.

Comment: But If I have only HTTP on my site, the cookie willl have to be sent in HTTP ? Or does this happen only if you emit the cookie from HTTPS first ?

Comment: The cookie will not be sent over HTTP, the "secure" flag will prevent that. But you can set the cookie over plain HTTP. set-cookie header can be sent over HTTP, even if the cookie it is setting has the secure flag. More on this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140940/can-a-secure-cookie-be-set-from-an-insecure-http-connection-if-so-why-is-it-al

Answer (score 0):

First of all using HTTP to transmit sensitive data is not a good idea whether you use query strings or any other mechanism because you are vulnerable in many ways. Even if you are using HTTPS, [there are many aspects you need to consider when you are deploying.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SSL_Best_Practices)

> protect a query string

I think you are concern about attacks such as XSS and SSRF here ? If you are using data in query string you must perform [data sanitation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) , URL encoding and most importantly server side data validation as well before you process your data.

Comment: I changed the question. Mainly focused on sniffing attacks. Can the JSESSIONID not be sniffed using HTTP?

Comment: Anything going on HTTP can be sniffed without knowing to the user. Check sslstrip as a MiTM attack.